# Stop interaction of mouse with the desktop in linux

Tags: linux, input, mouse

i want to take input of co-ordinates from a mouse when left mouse button is pressed for some experiment , but it interacts with the stuff on the desktop and messes up things . Is there anyway to stop mouse from interacting with objects , like disable mouse click or something like that .

PS:I already have X11 connection to X server , i am using XQuerryPointer to get the co-ordinates, this application is windowless which outputs stuff on the terminal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabPointer.html can do what you want. To receive the input coordinates I assume you already got an X11 connection to the X Server?

Ok, here is the code that works.

```
Display *dpy;
dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
int g=XGrabPointer(dpy,DefaultRootWindow(dpy), true, ButtonPressMask |
                 ButtonReleaseMask |
                 PointerMotionMask |
                 FocusChangeMask |
                EnterWindowMask |
                  LeaveWindowMask,GrabModeAsync,GrabModeAsync, None, None, CurrentTime);
```

Comment: yes , i already have X11 connection to X server , i am using XQuerryPointer to get the co-ordinates .

Comment: I don't seem to understand(from the link) about how to stop mouse pointer to interact with any other window or icon. PS: my program has no window .

Comment: i haven't done it myself, but i suppose you'll need to register a fullscreen window to stop events from propagating ... screensavers do similar things